# Open chrome with default user profile using python and selenium on mac

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to get Selenium to open Chrome just as if I was opening it myself, i.e. I should be logged into my accounts like Facebook.

I have the following code:

```
def startChrome():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/alexiseggermont/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
    return driver

driver = startChrome()
url = 'https://www.facebook.com'
driver.get(url)
```

However this gets me to Facebook without being logged in. I have checked `chrome://version` and the profile URL is in fact correct. What am I doing wrong?

Using Python 3, Chrome Version 63.0.3239.84, MacOS High Sierra

Comment: Are you sure, when you open Chrome normally, you are logged into Facebook?

Comment: @ubadub, yes I am, just checked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the `Default/` from the end of your path

`options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/alexiseggermont/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/")`

On a PC, it would typically be something like:

`options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:/Users/{USERNAME}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data')`

You'll need to check you've got compatible versions of chromedriver and chrome - the easiest way to do that, is to check that both are up to date.

If it crashes immediately on opening, check [the chromedriver help page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/chrome-doesn-t-start). Maybe try disabling all extensions, to see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to open a new window with the right profile, but then it crashes (Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522932 (4140ab217e1ca1bec0c4b4d1b148f3361eb3a03e),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.2 x86_64))

Comment: Ah, I don't really know much about Macs. Is there anything here that helps: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/chrome-doesn-t-start . And maybe disable all extensions, see if that helps.

Comment: Linux ubuntu: '/home/<usr_name>/.config/google-chrome/Default'

Comment: For me, it works

chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/profileName")

Comment: this also works for me, and i can start more than one webdriver with it, but it does give an error.

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to EnergyNumbers' answer, you also have to make sure that you've actually quit chrome before launching your script.

In my case I constantly got the error `Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)`

But that instantly disappeared when I quit chrome before launching the script. Apparantly, no 2 instances of the same profile can be opened at the same time.